# get edited data automatically not using page refresh

Tags: angular

What I insert data in the database is getting into ngOninit initially. Here I am trying to get edited data without page refresh but what I am facing an issue is updated data appends to my previous getting data.

What I need is which data I update that I want to show. I don't want to show my previous data again. I am showing my browser image in below, On that, I update cell phones in place of mobiles. Data is getting but it displays my previous data also.

Can anyone please help.

[image]

**My TS File**

```
 ngOnInit() {
          this.getting_category();
    }

getting_category(){
this.accountService.get_Category().subscribe(response=>{
  this.get_cat=response;
  for(var i=0;i<this.get_cat.length;i++){
    this.cat_name.push(this.get_cat[i].category_name);
  }
  for(var i=0;i<this.get_cat.length;i++){
    this.cat_id.push(this.get_cat[i]._id);
  }
  })
}


    /////Update Category/////
    cat_update(){
  let data={
  id:this.catdata[0]._id,
  category_name:this.category_name
  }
  this.accountService.updatecategory(data).subscribe(response=>{

    // this.Tmp=0;
    this.cat_name.clear();
this.getting_category();
alert("successfully updated")
  } ,err=>{
  alert("Something went wrong while update");
  })
  }
```

**My Html**

```
<div *ngIf="Tmp==0 else noTmp">
            <select   multiple id="sel1" name="category" (change)="change_fun($event)"  [(ngModel)]="catname" class="form-control">
                <option *ngFor="let x of cat_name" [value]="x">{{x}}</option>
            </select>
            <ng-template #noTmp>
                    <select   multiple id="sel1" name="category" (change)="change_fun($event)"  [(ngModel)]="catname" class="form-control">
                            <option *ngFor="let x of cat_name" [value]="x">{{x}}</option>
                        </select>
            </ng-template>
        </div>
```

**My service**

```
updatecategory(data):Observable<any>{
    return (this.http.post(this.apiPath + 'user/updatecategory', data).pipe(map(this.dt)));
    }
```

Comment: You're calling `getting_category()` after updating, but in `getting_category()` you did not clear `this.cat_name` array. Ideal you shouldn't be calling `getting_category()` after update. Just push it to the array. Though your object look very messy.

Comment: Now i update my cat_update function can you please give a look on that. But i am getting same result. I used clear().

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which programming language is this but when we load data using ajax we empty the data of that dropdown using empty() method in js and then append the new data

Comment: I am new to angular. Can you please give me info in code format relate to my code.

Comment: Just before appending updated data empty that dropdown using its id like $('#dropdownid').empty(); and then append data to that dropdown this is what we do in js usually this might be help you

Answer (score 0):

you should call **this.cat_name.clear();** before putting data inside.

```
this.accountService.get_Category().subscribe(
this.get_cat=response;
this.cat_name.clear() // clear list before loading data 
for(var i=0;i<this.get_cat.length;i++){
   this.cat_name.push(this.get_cat[i].category_name);
}
```